How enable a Fast Up-to-Date Check (FUTDC) support for custom MSBuild target
I use VS 2022 and I have RCL .net project. It contains the following structure:

My project on build runs npm run build command through the Build_WelcomeDashboardAssets target.
Here my package.json file:
{
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/package",
    "name": "test.welcomedashboard",
    "private": true,
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "watch": "tsc && vite build --watch",
        "build": "tsc && vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@umbraco-cms/backoffice": "15.1.1",
        "@types/node": "22.9.0",
        "typescript": "5.6.3",
        "vite": "5.4.11"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "lit": "3.2.1"
    },
    "volta": {
        "node": "22.9.0"
    }
}

and my vite.config.ts file:
import { defineConfig, UserConfig } from "vite";
import { ModuleFormat } from "rollup";

// Read more here: https://vite.dev/config/

export default defineConfig(({}) => {
    const config: UserConfig = {
        build: {
            minify: "esbuild",
            lib: {
                entry: [
                    "src/entry.ts",
                ],
                formats: ["es"],
                fileName: (format: ModuleFormat, entryName: string) => `${entryName}.js` // output js file name
            },
            outDir: "../../wwwroot/App_Plugins/TEST.WelcomeDashboard",
            emptyOutDir: true,
            sourcemap: true,
            rollupOptions: {
                external: [/^@umbraco/]
            }
        }
    };

    return config;
});


Vite - just a bundler like webpack. So on .csproj build all my files from App_PLugins/TEST.WelcomeDashboard/src are bundled to wwwroot/App_Plugins/TEST.WelcomeDashboard/entry.js and App_PLugins/TEST.WelcomeDashboard/umbraco-package.json copied to wwwroot/App_Plugins/TEST.WelcomeDashboard/umbraco-package.json.
My project has with the following .csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net9.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <StaticWebAssetBasePath>/</StaticWebAssetBasePath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Build_WelcomeDashboardAssets" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Running npm build" />
    <Exec Command="npm run build" WorkingDirectory="App_Plugins/TEST.WelcomeDashboard" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="CleanWelcomeDashboardAssets" BeforeTargets="Clean">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Clean welcome" />
    <RemoveDir Directories="wwwroot/App_Plugins/TEST.WelcomeDashboard" />
  </Target>

</Project>

Each time when I build project target Build_WelcomeDashboardAssets triggered.
I need to trigger Build_WelcomeDashboardAssets target only when files in ./App_Plugins/TEST.WelcomeDashboard where changed. If not target Build_WelcomeDashboardAssets should be skipped.
I tried to add Inputs and Outputs to target to enable ast Up-to-Date Check (FUTDC) support but it does not work:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net9.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <StaticWebAssetBasePath>/</StaticWebAssetBasePath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Build_WelcomeDashboardAssets" BeforeTargets="Build"
          Inputs="@(App_Plugins/TEST.WelcomeDashboard/**)"
          Outputs="wwwroot/App_Plugins/TEST.WelcomeDashboard/entry.js;wwwroot/App_Plugins/TEST.WelcomeDashboard/umbraco-package.json">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Running npm build" />
    <Exec Command="npm run build" WorkingDirectory="App_Plugins/TEST.WelcomeDashboard" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="CleanWelcomeDashboardAssets" BeforeTargets="Clean">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Clean welcome" />
    <RemoveDir Directories="wwwroot/App_Plugins/TEST.WelcomeDashboard" />
  </Target>

</Project>

I expect that after two builds in row, second build should be completed faster (it should skip Build_WelcomeDashboardAssets target), but it does not.
Are there any way to enable FUTDC for my target?
